How can I print out the last element in each row of a pyramid in Java
In Java, I'm looking to read a file in with 6 lines of information and print out the 1st, 3rd, 6th element. This is kinda like a pyramid, but doesn't have to be printed as such, just for sake of reference.
  1
 2 3
4 5 6

The data in the file is as follows:
3 love
6 computers
2 dogs
4 cats
1 I
5 you
And I need it to print:
1: I
3: love
6: computers
I've used a HashMap<Integer, String> to put the entries in a pair which might be overkill, but it's "how to print out the last term in the row" that's killing me.  I believe it's pretty simple n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4, ... notation, but for the life of me any algorithmic / design pattern is not coming to light to be able to solve this.  I looked at a "14 pyramid patterns" site -> [https://www.tutorialsfreak.com/java-tutorial/examples/pyramid-patterns] and a few others, all show me how to print out a pyramid, which is simple, but none tell me how to reference the last object in the row of a pyramid, and that's what the goal is.
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        HashMap<Integer, String> mapOfInputs = new HashMap<>();
        BufferedReader reader; 
        
        try { 
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\temp\\Foo.txt")); 
            String fileLine = reader.readLine();
            
            while (fileLine != null) { // indicates EoF
                int number = Integer.parseInt(fileLine.substring(0, 1));
                mapOfInputs.put(number, fileLine.substring(2, fileLine.length()));
                fileLine = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfEx) { 
            System.out.println("File not found"); 
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
            System.out.println("Check your file, not formatted correctly.  Expecting ->  [Number][Space][Word]");
        }
        
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = mapOfInputs.entrySet().iterator();
        
        int counter = 1;
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {            
            Map.Entry<Integer, String> element = (Entry<Integer, String>) iterator.next();
            if (element.getKey() == counter) {              
                System.out.println(element.getKey() + ": " + element.getValue());
                counter++;
            } else {
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
        
        }
    }

}```


idea: for (i=j=1; i<=10;j++,i+=j) System.out.println(i); (must be expanded, adapted, ...) [j++,i+=j can be written as i += ++j] {the idea is to increment the increment at each iteration}

For a quick fix with step-wise increment there is shmosel's answer. Here, I explain the formula based approach.
Triangular number
See Wikipedia Triangular number.
To get the number of rows for a pyramid, given the number of elements as x see Triangular roots and tests for triangular numbers and use a formula like in this function:
// given x elements, the return is the number of rows (truncated)
int rowsOfPyramid = (int) ((Math.sqrt((8*x)+1) -1) / 2.00);

For your 6 elements (size of the map with read lines) this function will return 3 rows.
Then use this 3 rows in a for loop to print the last element for each row.
For the first row it will be the first element: n=1 means index=1,
for the second row n=2 means index=3 and n=3 means index=6.
See Triangular number, Formula:
int index = (n * (n+1)) / 2;

Simple for loop over pyramid rows
Then you can use a simple get on the map inside the loop like:
int x =  mapOfInputs.size();
int rowsOfPyramid = (int) ((Math.sqrt((8*x)+1) -1) / 2.00);
System.out.println("Pyramid has rows: " + rowsOfPyramid);

for (int n = 1; n <= rowsOfPyramid; n++ ) {
  int index = (n * (n+1)) / 2;  // Triangular number, formula
  System.out.println(index + ": " + mapOfInputs.get(index));
}

Try demo with source on IDEone.

Well, i guess i just rederived some math that obviously already existed in my answer lol. Btw you don't have to use the triangular roots to know how long to loop for you can just iterate until your triangular number is out of bounds of the list(saving you a couple clock cycles in square root operations)

@MRtecno98, Decided against this n++ until out-of-bounds approach or premature optimization, in favor of a very deterministic and safe approach.

Looks like my approach of getting an iterator was overly heavy handed and the wrong approach.  I appreciate the explanation.  This is something that I'm going to read on.  When I read on my initial approach, it was all "print stars or alphanumeric characters".  Thank you for clearing this up.

You just need a simple loop that increments your index by an increasing amount:
for (int row = 1, offset = 1; map.containsKey(row); row += ++offset) {
    System.out.println(row + ": " + map.get(row));
}

Ideone Demo

So basically this is a math problem, you need to get the last element of a certain row, so you have the row number as input(let's call it r) and want the element absolute index(counting from the very start of the list) as the output (let's call it s).
So s is a function of r, if we try to manually write down some of its values we find a pattern:
s(1) = 0     # the index of the last element of the 
             # first row is just the first element

s(2) = 2     #    a    the index of the last element of the second row
             #  b   d  is 2, because its the third element in the sequence

# now to get the last element in the third row, we start from the
# last element in the second row and go forward 3 elements

s(3) = s(2)+3 = 2+3 = 5  # so the last element of the third row has
                         # index 5, which is correct

So to find the last element of the r-th row we just get the index of the last element of row r - 1 plus the number of elements in row r(which is just r)
s(1) = 0
s(r) = s(r - 1) + r

You could just implement it recursively like this but we can expand it to simplify it a bit(if you don't want to read through the math just skip to the end).
s(r) = r + r - 1 + r - 2 + r - 3 + ...

Rearranging the terms
s(r) = (r + r + ... + r) + (- 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - ... - (r - 1)) =
     = r^2 - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (r - 1))

The sum of all positive integers from 1 to r - 1 is equal to:
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (r - 1) = (r - 1)(r)/2

And so our function becomes:
s(r) = r^2 - r(r - 1)/2 = r(r + 1)/2

And we're done with the math, if you want you can go back to when we calculated some of the values by hand to confirm they are still consistent.
Now to implement it it's just a matter of writing the(algorithmically trivial) function we found before and using it to get our indexes.
public static int lastRowElement(int row) {
    return r*(r + 1) / 2 // integer division
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> inputs = new HashMap<>();

    /* ... open file and do parsing ... */
    while(...) {
        inputs.put(i, element);
    }

    // Print last element of every row
    for(int r = 0;; r++) {
        String element = inputs.get(lastRowElement(r));
        if(element == null) 
            break; // We reached a row that doesn't exist
        System.out.println("Row: " + r + "  Last row element: " + element);
    }
}


Thank you for explaining the math behind this.  That's where I was getting hemmed up with.

Here is one way.
Allocate a record to hold the number and word. Override toString to display as required. Also instantiate a TreeSet to sort the data as it is entered.  The sort is based on the number.
record Data(int n, String word) {
     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return n + " : " + word;
     }
}
TreeSet<Data> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Data::n));

Read in the data

I am using a String to hold the data but a Scanner can be used to read from the terminal.

String input = """
         3 love
         6 computers
         2 dogs
         4 cats
         1 I
         5 you
         """;

Read in the data and add to the set
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
 while (s.hasNextLine()) {
     set.add(new Data(s.nextInt(), s.next()));
     s.nextLine();
 }

Add to an array List for indexing
 ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>(set);

Now the heart of the program. Iterate over the list incrementing by k which is also incrementing by 1.  This provides the index of the desired element.
 int k = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i += k++) {
     System.out.println(list.get(i));
 }

prints
1 : I
3 : love
6 : computers

